# fopen/fwrite and multi-threading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, fopen

fopen/fwrite and multi-threading?

Some multi-threading programs open the same file, each thread create a file pointer to that the file.

There is one thread created by a paricular program that will update the file at some random time, whilst other threads, created by a different program, will simply read the contents of the file.

I guess this create a racing/data-inconsistence problem there if the writing thread change contents in the file whilst other threads try to read the contents.

The problem here is the thread that update the file should compiled into a different exe program than the the program that creates threads that read the contents of the file, so within-program level thread control become impossible.

My solution is create a very small "flag" file on the harddisk to indicates 3 status of the file:

1) writing-thread is updating the contents of the file;

2) reading-thread are reading the contents of the file;

3) Neither 1) or 2);

Using this flag file to block threads whenever necessary.

Are there some more-compact/neat solution to this problem?

Comment: What you propose is a semaphore and it's a fine solution :-)

You could lock the file or you could put your semaphore as the first byte of the file...either way it's not really about multithreading.

Comment: There are file locks. And the main concurrency issues you presented are between processes, not threads. On which OS are you?

Comment: can you explain futher about file locks? and how to use them, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use a process-global "named" semaphore that all the processes know about.  Plus then you could use thread/process-blocking semaphore mechanisms instead of spin-looping on file-open-close and file contents...